# Why doesn't it work as expected?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog() { Description = "Select your path" })
            {
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    tbxFrom.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myLyndaFiles = Directory.GetFiles(tbxFrom.Text, ".lynda");
            var lynda = Directory.GetFiles(tbxProgrammLocation.Text, ".exe");
            for (int i = 0; i < myLyndaFiles.Length; i++) 
            {
                Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", lynda[0] + " /F " + myLyndaFiles[i] +  " " + tbxTo.Text + "\n");
                tbxOut.Text = i.ToString(); 
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog() { Description = "Select your path" })
            {
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    tbxTo.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void btnStartFrom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog() { Description = "Select your path" })
            {
                if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    tbxProgrammLocation.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please someone help me! I don't know why but `Directory.GetFiles` doesn't work as it looks like. I looked into the `var myLyndaFiles` via breakpoint but I get that it is null more or less [0] --> but there are more than 20 files there...

Comment: Post only the necessary code

Comment: PS These are the inputs:

Comment: tbxProgrammLocation:
C:\Users\Kamil\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test

Comment: tbxFrom: 
D:\Lynda\ldc_dl_courses\164452

Comment: Do not add parts of the question via comments, and as @Sajeetharan said, reduce the code in the question to the part you actually have problems with or the question will probably be closed as unclear.

Comment: Please read on how to create a [mcve]

Comment: tbxTo:
D:\Test....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to be (add wildcard on your extension files):

```
 var myLyndaFiles = Directory.GetFiles(tbxFrom.Text, "*.lynda");
 var lynda = Directory.GetFiles(tbxProgrammLocation.Text, "*.exe");
```

and not:

```
 var myLyndaFiles = Directory.GetFiles(tbxFrom.Text, ".lynda");
 var lynda = Directory.GetFiles(tbxProgrammLocation.Text, ".exe");
```

Comment: great thx didn't see that :P